# WPF Border thickness bottom only..

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I'm trying to create WPF button with only border on the bottom and the rest will hide. I try to use borderthickness = "0,0,0,1" but it doesn't work.. here is my codes..

```
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Width="235" Padding="5" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="260">
<Image Source="Images/room-32.png" Height="20" Margin="30,0,8,0"/>
<TextBlock Width="200">Station Maintenance</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the `BorderBrush` is set to `Transparent`. Assign a color to it.

```
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black"  Width="235" Padding="5" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="260">
      <Image Source="Images/room-32.png" Height="20" Margin="30,0,8,0"/>
      <TextBlock Width="200">Station Maintenance</TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

So, instead of

```
BorderBrush="Transparent"
```

use

```
BorderBrush="Black" // Any color you would like
```

**EDIT**

If you want a border around your `button` that even is visible on `hover`, etc... than add a `border element` around your `button`.

```
  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
      <Button Background="Transparent"
              Width="235"
              Padding="5"
              FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                      Width="260">
               <Image Source="Images/room-32.png"
                     Height="20"
                     Margin="30,0,8,0" />
               <TextBlock Width="200">Station Maintenance</TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
      </Button>
  </Border>
```

Comment: I try it in that way Loetn But, Instead of having a border on bottom part only it triggers the other part too. I don't know what the problem is. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @eiv What do you mean with 'it triggers the other part too'? I made an edit, is that what you want?

Comment: @eiv Did you solve it in a different way than I did? If yes, can you consider to add your solution as an answer so that other people know how you solved it.

Comment: No Loetn, I did it using your solution. thank you so much for the help.